# How to show Realtime/Streaming Graph on Jsp page

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp

How can I plot realtime data with JQuery, Ajax?

The data will be fetched from MySQL/SQL database. I want to show this realtime graph on a JSP page.

Comment: Do you have a graph drawing plugin? if yes, then it is simply a matter of setting an interval and making the ajax call for the data indefinitely and passing the data to the graph drawing plugin.

Comment: Which plugin should i use?

Comment: Its really up to you. There are a bunch of them out there ( fusioncharts, d3, google charts and many more)..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My suggestion is to use **CanvasJS**. It really helps you for easiest and dynamic data plotting.
Checkout [JSP Demo Gallery](https://canvasjs.com/jsp-charts/)

Check [this page](https://canvasjs.com/jsp-charts/json-data-api-ajax-chart/) for an chart rendered from JSON file using AJAX request.